# In TinyMCE how do you deal with images uploaded to the server and then deleted in the editor?

Tags: tinymce

I have images uploaded to the server working in TinyMCE via drag-and-drop and the image upload dialog. They get saved with different naming conventions, but it works.

If a user deletes a post, I can do a backend check and delete associated images.

But how does TinyMCE deal with images deleted in the following cases?

1. An image is uploaded while editing. It gets immediately saved on the server, even before the post is saved. What if the user decided to delete the image in the post they are editing. How does the already-uploaded image get deleted?
2. What about if a user goes back and edits a post and deletes an image? How does TinyMCE deal with the image, which is already on the server?
3. Or what if the post is never saved and the user has added images to it? They are instantly saved on the server. How do they get deleted?

Do people just live with extra, unused images on the server?

Thanks,

doug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TinyMCE is not designed to directly address these sort of image management and uploading edge cases. They can (and should be managed) but it is out of TinyMCE's scope to do so with built in functionality.

One method to ensure you are not left with orphaned files is to not upload them to your server until the document itself is submitted to be saved. Many of the edge cases you discuss could be addressed by changing the `automatic_uploads` setting.

When an image is added to TinyMCE, it is added inline to content as a base64 encoded blob URL. You have the option to configure uploading that image to your database, afterwhich, the `src` of the image tag is updated with the image's remote, database location.

However, if you turn `automatic_uploads` off, then images will only be uploaded when `editor.uploadImages()` is called. This could allow users to add and remove images to content while creating it, but for only their final version of the content (and images) to be saved into the database.

Here's some more information:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#automatic_uploads

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/

If an end-user loads existing content that includes an image (already saved to the database) but removes that image from content and then re-saves the content, one way to account for this is to parse content as it is loaded into the editor, and make a list/array/object of all included media assets, and then compare that to the the assets in content upon save. Then you could use that list to update the database accordingly. TinyMCE does not offer one specific method to do this, because there are so many different ways of implementing this sort of behavior.

Another option is to make orphan control server maintenance a completely separate task from the editing process. One approach for this would be to run regularly-scheduled background maintenance task on server that parses content, and looks for orphaned image files.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer. I reached much of the same conclusions. On our server we have filters associated with editing (post and pre) which I can see using to handle some of this. For example, initially upload the images to a temp area, then when the user saves the post run a filter to move the images to the live imageUploads folder and use a RegEx to update the img tag src properties. Similarly, when deleting a post, I could run a "pre" filter that first finds the mentioned images and deletes them from the live imageUploads folder.

Comment: If you turn `automatic_uploads` off then don't you see the base64 contents if you switch to show source while editing?

Comment: Tiny Lincoln, your reply was pretty good, but there is another small issue not mentioned, what if an end user uploads more than one of the same image and then decides to remove one of them? With all having the same filename and other properties would make parsing really difficult.

Answer (score 1):

To handle image upload:

```
tinymce.init({
  images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
    formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
    //here make your post to upload the file, heres an example with axios
    axios.post("http://myurl.com/upload", formData)
      .then((response){
         //response should have the path for the image uploaded
         //if everything is fine, call success() with the path for the image
         success(response.image_path); //or whatever your variable name
      })
}
```

To delete images:

- add a setup event for reading a keydown event
- verify you had an image selected
- then make the call to your server to delete the image src

```
tinymce.init({
  setup(editor) {
    editor.on("keydown", function(e){
      if ((e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) && tinymce.activeEditor.selection) {
         var selectedNode = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();
         if (selectedNode && selectedNode.nodeName == 'IMG') {
            var imageSrc = selectedNode.src;
            //here you can call your server to delete the image
         }

       }
    });
   }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't allow for the possibility that someone might upload an image and then click 'undo'